# Using mySQL on Tomcat server?

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I have the following problem at the moment.
I am using mySQL and Tomcat for my college project, and I am able to connect mySQL DB locally from a jsp page. However, if I try to use mySQL and server in my college, I got the following error

`Exception: Communications link failure. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

Just wondering if anyone has the experience before and how to solve it?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So locally it works fine, but at college not? Then it's a matter of a firewall at the college. Contact the network admin of the college for support.

Comment: Just for an update this issue, the previous question is based on the network at my home. I had tried to connect mySQL by using network in my college and the result is successfully retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a firewall issue, it could be blocking incoming connections on the MySQL port (by default, 3306).  To see if that's the case, you could try telnetting into the MySQL server and port and seeing if you're denied access.

Here's a [Sun forums post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5263225) which discusses this error.

Comment: Thanks,Kaleb
I forget to mention that I am using Windows.
My connector/J is 5.1.10 and I am using JDK 1.6. (I think there is no problems with them)
Also, my firewall is turned off.
But I still got the same error.